# Why is sockstat TCP on the host able to correspond to the number in the container, but socksat Used is not?

Tags: docker, prometheus-node-exporter, linux-namespaces

One host, check the contents of `/proc/net/sockstat`:

```
cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 245
TCP: inuse 6 orphan 4 tw 1 alloc 2696 mem 95
UDP: inuse 4 mem 10
UDP: inuse 4 mem 10
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

But check it in the containers:

```
cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 886
TCP: inuse 3 orphan 2 tw 49 alloc 2699 mem 105
UDP: inuse 1 mem 10
UDP: inuse 1 mem 10
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

The number of `used sockets` seen in the host is too low to match the actual number (lots of tcp allocated in the container). Why?